# Kalman filter implementation: position with only accelerometer input

Tags: accelerometer, estimation, kalman-filter

I'm quite new to the world of Kalman filter, so I have some doubts about it.

I will use a simple case study:

if we have a 1 dimensional world where a body is moving with a changeable acceleration, could it be possible to estimate its current position and velocity with a Kalman Filter? (since accelerometer measurements could be noisy). I found a lot of examples, but they use other kinds of tracking techniques like GPS. I would like to understand if an accelerometer could be enough to estimate the state and how to set up the Kalman Filter.

Thank you in advance,
Michele

Comment: The short answer is no, a Kalman filter is of no use estimating position if the only sensor you have is an accelerometer.  When acceleration is integrated to get velocity one has one unknown constant (the initial velocity).  When the velocity is integrated to get position, we get a second unknown constant, the initial position.  Further measurements from the accelerometer provide no information about the initial position or the initial velocity, and they cannot be resolved with the accelerometer alone.  There must be other sensors, or other information, to estimate the position.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it's clear.

Answer (score 2):

Kalman filter is often used to combine measurements from different sources (e.g. accelerations from accelometer, angular velocity from gyro, and absolute position measurements from GPS).

Usually you define what is the state variable that describe the current status of your system (e.g. position, velocity, acceleration). And provides a process model (what you believe the state should behaved -- in your case, a constant acceleration model), and a measurement model (how the current state you be observed). In your case, the measurement model H can only observe acceleration, and never have any information about position. The essentially making this Kalman filter *unobservable*, you can think of it as a under-determined system.

With no measurements governing the position state, the covariance matrix P will just keep blowing up, and no way it can provide anything close to realistic value.

So the answer is No, you are not able to use Kalman filter with a constant acceleration model without any absolute measurements of position keeping it from blowing up.